# How to reuse the code in all aws lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Programming Language - Java

We have 10 different aws lambda function. here we need to have same functionality for all the 10 lambda function. Instead of duplicating the same functionality 10 time. We can create common functionality and packaging as a framework jar and call them in each aws lambda function.

My question is how and where to deploy the jar file in aws and how we can include that jar file in all lambda functions and how to call the particular function in aws lambda function.

Answer (score 4):

Now that [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) are available you can use one Layer to share a jar file between multiple Lambda Functions.

Similarly to Lambda Functions you create Layers using a zip file. To share your custom code you'll need a zip file like follows:

```
my-layer.zip
└ java/lib/my-custom.jar
```

Then you can create your Lambda Functions on top of your custom layer and reference `my-custom.jar` as if it would be in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is; you can make only one lambda function, and placed an API Gateway in front of it. With the params from API Gateway, you can parse the lambda.

In example;

1 - Your main lambda handler function is parsing the "extension" parameter

2 - API Gateway gets and sends "extension" parameter to Lambda

3 - Lambda checks if extension is xml, xmlParser() will work or if .jar jarParser will works.

So there is no need to make 10 lambda functions.

Best,

Comment: Thanks for a reply.

Comment: Actually what I am trying to express is, I am creating one common framework jar which consist of service layer and DAO layer. I want to call the particular service from my lambda function. Here all lambda functions must be depends on that framework jar. My question is where that jar will be deployed and how it will be deployed and how I should import that jar in my lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node.js, [this](https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/nodejs-runtime-environment-with-aws-lambda-layers-f3914613e20e) article is really great and explains pretty well.